# executing a function in sql plus

Tags: oracle, function, sqlplus

I created a function in oracle that inserts records in specific tables and return an output according to what occurs within the function. e.g (ins_rec return number)

How do I call this function and see its output in sql plus

Answer (score 39):

```
declare
  x number;
begin
  x := myfunc(myargs);
end;
```

Alternatively:

```
select myfunc(myargs) from dual;
```

Comment: `select myfunc(myargs) from dual;` worked for me. I had issues with the `delcare` version.

Comment: I have a function that calls a procedure. If I use this method to call the function, I get a DML write exception. If I use the "exec dbms_output...." call, it works without errors

Comment: You can't use a function that _modifies data_ in a `select` statement.

Comment: @Alex78191 `select` statements are meant to be non-DML, i.e. perform no updates to data. The error you get would be `ORA-14551: cannot perform a DML operation inside a query`.

Answer (score 12):

One option would be:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

EXEC DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(your_fn_name(your_fn_arguments));
```

Answer (score 5):

As another answer already said, call `select myfunc(:y) from dual;` , but you might find declaring and setting a variable in sqlplus a little tricky:

```
sql> var y number

sql> begin
  2  select 7 into :y from dual;
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

sql> print :y

         Y
----------
         7

sql> select myfunc(:y) from dual;
```