# Oracle Variable as select

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have to call oracle SQL statement inside my project.

All connection related stuff is done, but my tool does not capture the output parameter executed by oracle.

Hence I need alter this query to return `p_num` value in a select statement.

i.e. the table which has 1 column ('p_num') with column name called 'Result' and which has only one row which is `p_num` value.

Following is the sql statement which currently gives output value with help of `dbms_output.put_line`

```
DECLARE
p_num varchar2(4000);
message varchar2(4000) ; 
BEGIN
p_num := MyFunction();

dbms_output.put_line('Message : ' || p_num) ;
    END;
```

What I want is `p_num` value in a `SELECT` statement so that I can capture specific column inside my bpm tool.

Comment: Which SELECT statement? There is no select statement in your question

Comment: i want value of p_num shoudl be in resultset, so that my bpm tool captures output result value,
i want some thing like
select p_num from temp_table

Comment: Which result? Show us the query you want to change

Comment: Not sure, but may be you are looking for this :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127482/executing-a-function-in-sql-plus

Comment: in above sql statment i have value in p_num, which i want to be in the form of select statments table result

Comment: when i put select * from dual i am getting a result as 'X' in dummy column,
i want similar kind of result where in stood of 'X' it should be value from p_num

Answer (score 1):

You can directly call the function in the SELECT statement.

1) First way is to do it VIA plain SQL

```
SELECT MyFunction FROM DUAL;
```

2) Second way is PLSQL but i will not recommend it unless its unavoidable

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
lv_var VARCHAR2(100);
lv_out_param VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
lv_var:=MyFunction(lv_out_param);
dbms_output.put_line(lv_var||' '||lv_out_param);
END;
/
```

Comment: I am new to oracle , Wat is this DUAL, Keyword?
When i execute select Myfunction('APPR') from DUAL it says

ORA-06550: line 9, column 5:
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

Comment: DUAL is a built-in table with a single row and column. It is used when you just want to evaluate an expression and aren't really interested in the table data.

Comment: Regarding PLS-00428: Do no use PL/SQL, i.e. remove DECLARE, BEGIN, END and just execute the SELECT statement without anything else.

Comment: @user3815413 : I have added both the ways of achieving the solution. Let me know if this helps. And explained  above  DUAL is a dummy table which ORACLE has provided.

Comment: Thank you so much Avrajit,Thanks a alot for quick responce
Now it is saying, Function MyFunction  has out arguments,
How can i passs out argumenst without declare?

Comment: Then it cant be called via plain SQL. You need to do it via PLSQL only

Comment: I have modified the answer as per your comment. Could you plz check

Comment: This was giving the result but not as table, which cannot be captured in bpm tool.
ithink select statement result it will capture since it was table like result

Comment: when i write select * from dual i am getting a result as 'X' in dummy column,
i want similar kind of result where in stood of 'X' it should be value from p_num